# Why am I getting an extra space when I remove this line break?

Tags: php, string

```
$metaInfo = file_get_contents('assets/php/'.$url[0].'/meta.ini');
$metaInfo = str_ireplace("\n","&",$metaInfo);
```

The data looks like this BEFORE strip the break tags and replace it with an ampersand:

```
[Page Information]
pageFile=main.php
pageTitle=Home Page

[Overwrite Meta Tags]    
metaDescription=The main page in our website.
metaKeywords=My, Insanely, Awesome, Website
metaAuthor=Jake Andreoli
```

The data I get after I'm done:

```
[Page Information] &pageFile=main.php &pageTitle=Home Page &[Overwrite Meta Tags] & &metaDescription=The main page in our website. &metaKeywords=My, Insanely, Awesome, Website &metaAuthor=Jake Andreoli
```

While this is almost correct, it adds an additional space to every variable. I really can't figure it out, someone help me out?

Comment: First of all, you have some space after `[Overwrite Meta Tags]` but before the line break. Also, could it be caused by `\r` characters in the file? Do you apply any other transformations to the file besides those lines you posted?

Comment: Sure.  The `str_ireplace` method isn't adding spaces.  Those spaces are already in your file.  If you copy/pasted into this site directly from it I can see multiple spaces after the `[Overwrite Meta Tags]` tag.

Comment: I don't see any spaces in my editor. Using Dreamweaver CS6 and Notepad++

Comment: Rule #101 of coding.  If your output has more spaces than your input does then you don't know what your input is. ;)

Comment: Try replacing "\r\n" as already suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is either a trailing space at the end of each line or there is a \r which may be causing it.  Open in an editor that will show \r and help find trailing spaces.  If a space, then replace on " \n".  If a \r then replace "\r\n" (common on windows).

Comment: Yeah that worked. I don't understand the whole trailing space thing, something I better look into. I know some editors can leave whitespace, but didn't really get it. Thanks (will accept when possible)

Comment: Also, might be worth looking at parse_ini_file()

Comment: That being a thing irritates me. But this works perfectly for what I want, so it's fine.